# Referencing DLLs in SSIS scripts

Tags: c#, dll, ssis

In my SSIS script component I would like to reference a dll with some of my custom code. When I reference the DLL in the script project VS adds it to the reference tree and all classes from my custom namespace are visible. However, when I build the project it complains about invalid namespace, just like the reference wasn't there.

Is there anything I need to do with that dll? I tried signing it and putting into GAC but it didn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you pressed save all after adding the reference?

Also see http://microsoft-ssis.blogspot.com/2011/05/referencing-custom-assembly-inside.html

Comment: I had troubles with this approach until I found out that my SSIS project targets .net 4.0 while my dll was targeting 4.5